# Android studio get data from html and filter only some value to show on textView

Tags: java, android, mongodb, okhttp

I have data from mongoDB and I can show on textView 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VuQz.png)

so I want to show some data on textView.

Ex. Show only temperature: 24 humid: 50

**mycode**

```
package com.example.okhttp3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "http://10.36.16.20:4000/readdht/1";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();


                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                            textView.setText(myResponse);    

                        }
                    });
                }

                TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textView2.setText("Temperature: "); //show only temperature
                TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                textView3.setText("Humidity: "); // show only humid
            }
        });   

    } 

}
```

I try to get text from textView by getText(); and parse to some variable for split the word but It doesn't work . Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can convert **response.body().string()** into JSON and from that get temperature and Humidity data.

```
    val jsonarray = JSONArray(response.body().string());
    val jsonObj : JSONObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
    val temperature = jsonObj.get("t");
    val humidity = jsonObj.get("h");
```